# Rolling back processes in a try catch block

Tags: php

I have a whole bunch of processes, i.e database save / update calls, command line interactions inside a try catch block.

Im wondering, if it reaches an exception, does everything in the try curly brackets get rolled back and undone?

If not, what would be the best way of approaching this?

Comment: No, you typically use a [finally](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2013/02/12/php5-5-trycatchfinally/) if you do things that need to be released in case of an exception. If you only need to undo your changes in case of an exception, just put the code to undo your changes in the except block.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not control what your database server does. If you want a database transaction you need to instruct the database server to start one. This, of course, entirely depends on your DBMS.

Said that, if the database engine supports transaction, uncommitted data gets rollbacked automatically when script ends.